# Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am creating a game account, then transferring a certain amount from the user to this account. Afterwards, I determine the winner randomly by the system or the user, and transfer the total amount to the winning account. However, I get two different errors in both blocks in the following codes. Where am I doing wrong?

```
    pub fn play(ctx: Context<Play>, position: Position, corner: Corner) -> Result<()> {
        let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;

        // Check if the game is already completed
        if game.status == Status::Completed {
            return Err(ErrorCode::GameAlreadyCompleted.into());
        }

        // Set the player's position and corner
        game.position = position;
        game.corner = corner;
        game.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("game").unwrap();

        let randomness =
            recent_blockhashes::last_blockhash_accessor(&ctx.accounts.recent_blockhashes)?;

        // Select a random corner
        let random_corner: Corner = match randomness_tools::expand(randomness, 2) {
            0 => Corner::TopLeft,
            _ => Corner::TopRight,
        };

        // Get the recipient account
        let to = game.player;
        let amount = 100000000;

        // Transfer Solana lamports from the user account to the game account
        let transfer_to_game = solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.authority.key(),
            &game.to_account_info().key,
            amount,
        );
        solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &transfer_to_game,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
                game.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[b"transfer".as_ref(), &[0u8; 32]][..]],
        )?;

        // Transfer Solana lamports from the game account to the player account or the program owner account
        let transfer_to_winner_or_owner = if game.position == Position::Goalkeeper {
            match game.corner {
                Corner::TopLeft => None,
                _ => Some(to),
            }
        } else {
            match game.corner {
                Corner::TopRight => None,
                _ => Some(to),
            }
        };

        // TODO:
        // 1. Fix Issue:     Error:  An account required by the instruction is missing
        // 2. Fix Issue:     Error: Program failed to completeError: failed to send transaction:
        //                   Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation
        //                   with unauthorized signer or writable account

        if let Some(winner) = transfer_to_winner_or_owner {
            let transfer_to_winner = solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
                &game.to_account_info().key,
                &winner,
                amount,
            );
            solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
                &transfer_to_winner,
                &[
                    game.to_account_info(),
                    ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                ],
                &[&[b"transfer".as_ref(), &[0u8; 32]][..]],
            )?;
        } else {
            let transfer_to_owner = solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
                &game.to_account_info().key,
                &game.to_account_info().owner,
                amount,
            );
            solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
                &transfer_to_owner,
                &[
                    game.to_account_info(),
                    ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                ],
                &[&[b"transfer".as_ref(), &[0u8; 32]][..]],
            )?;
        }

        // Update the game status and random corner
        game.status = Status::Completed;
        game.corner = random_corner;

        Ok(())
    }


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Play<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + 100,
        seeds = [b"game", authority.key().as_ref()], bump
    )]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,
    /// CHECK: ?
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: sysvar address check is hardcoded, we want to avoid the default deserialization
    #[account(address = sysvar::recent_blockhashes::ID)]
    pub recent_blockhashes: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ?
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Game {
    pub player: Pubkey,
    pub position: Position,
    pub corner: Corner,
    pub payment: u64,
    pub status: Status,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

client:

```
  const getGamePDA = (game: PublicKey) => {
    const [PDA, _] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("game"), game.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    return PDA;
  };

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const game = new anchor.web3.Keypair();
    const player = new anchor.web3.Keypair();
    const gamePDA = getGamePDA(player.publicKey);

    //airdrop
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      player.publicKey,
      LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );

    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);

    await sleep(5000);

    const tx = await program.methods
      .play(
        {
          forward: {},
        },
        {
          topRight: {},
        }
      )
      .accounts({
        authority: player.publicKey,
        game: gamePDA,
        recentBlockhashes: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RECENT_BLOCKHASHES_PUBKEY,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([player])
      .rpc();

    console.log(tx);
    const gameAccount = await program.account.game.fetch(game.publicKey);
    console.log("Your game account", gameAccount);
    // console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error `Error:  An account required by the instruction is missing` means you haven't provided all the `AccountInfo` that the instruction needs. For the `transfer` instruction https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.15.2/sdk/src/system_transaction.rs#L53 I assume you need to provide the `AccountInfo` of the `dest` as well - which is like the `winner` or `game.to_account_info().owner`

The second error`Error: Program failed to complete Error: failed to send transaction: with unauthorized signer or writable account` would be caused by fact that the provided account for the CPI call (i.e., on the `transfer` invocation) was not provided as a signer and/or mutable account. In this case it's probably the `game` account. The client needs to mark the `game` account as mutable and it has to be the signer of the transaction sent to blockchain.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should have to make init function to init the game account
2. We can't transafer solana to PDA account. Only can transfer solana to SystemAccount.

Comment: You can transfer SOL to a PDA, same as any other account.